# Footer overlapping with a section CSS

Tags: html, css

Im developing a website, and im having trouble in the footer of my page. It is overlapping with the content above it.

CSS:

```
.downstuff{
  padding: .3em;
  color: #e9e9e9;
  background: #242424;
  text-align: end;
}
The thing it is overlapping
```

HTML:

```
<div class="downstuff">
      <p>Copyright © 2021 Oaknoak | Branded Furniture</p>
      <p>Manufacturer | Chennai</p>
    </div>

<section class="product-main">
        <div class="product-card">
            <img src="images/Prince Krish Sofa-set Ash.jpg" alt="Prince Krish" class="product-img">
            <h1><a href="princekrish.html">Prince Krish Sofa-Set<a></h1>
            <p class="price">₹10000</p>
            <p>Prince Krish Sofa Set is made out of premium Jute fabric, Venga wood base and  Kurl-on foams</p>
            <p><button class="btn-cart">Add to Cart</button></p>
          </div>
          <div class="product-card">
            <img src="images/Eden Corner Sofaa.jpg" alt="Eden Corner Sofa" class="product-img">
            <h1><a href="princekrish.html">Eden Corner Sofa<a></h1>
            <p class="price">₹10000</p>
            <p>Eden Sofa One of the most luxurious models designed for the ultimate comfort and relaxation. </p>
            <p><button class="btn-cart">Add to Cart</button></p>
          </div>
          <div class="product-card">
            <img src="images/Cozy Rope Hammok.jpg" alt="Cozy Rope Hammok" class="product-img">
            <h1><a href="princekrish.html"> Rope Hammock<a></h1>
            <p class="price">₹10000</p>
            <p>The New Oak’N Oak Cotton Rope Hammock, performance and comfort come together to create this Original.</p>
            <p><button class="btn-cart">Add to Cart</button></p>
          </div>
          <div class="product-card">
            <img src="images/bonair sofa.jpg" alt="Bonaire Sofa" class="product-img">
            <h1><a href="princekrish.html">Bonaire Sofa<a></h1>
            <p class="price">₹10000</p>
            <p>Bonaire Sofa One of the most luxurious models designed for the ultimate comfort and relaxation.</p>
            <p><button class="btn-cart">Add to Cart</button></p>
          </div>
          <div class="product-card">
            <img src="images/Matiz sofa.jpg" alt="Matiz Sofa" class="product-img">
            <h1><a href="images/Matiz sofa.jpg">Matiz Sofa<a></h1>
            <p class="price">₹10000</p>
            <p>Matiz Sofa One of the most luxurious models designed for the ultimate comfort and relaxation.</p>
            <p><button class="btn-cart">Add to Cart</button></p>
          </div>
          <div class="product-card">
            <img src="images/diva sofa.jpg" alt="Diva Sofa" class="product-img">
            <h1><a href="princekrish.html">Diva Sofa<a></h1>
            <p class="price">₹10000</p>
            <p>Diva Sofa One of the most luxurious models designed for the ultimate comfort and relaxation</p>
            <p><button class="btn-cart">Add to Cart</button></p>
          </div>
          <div class="product-card">
            <img src="images/Tango sofa.jpg" alt="Tango Sofa" class="product-img">
            <h1><a href="princekrish.html">Tango Sofa<a></h1>
            <p class="price">₹10000</p>
            <p>Tango Sofa One of the most luxurious models designed for the ultimate comfort and relaxation.</p>
            <p><button class="btn-cart">Add to Cart</button></p>
          </div>
          <div class="product-card">
            <img src="images/Noor sofa.jpg" alt="Noor Sofa Malt" class="product-img">
            <h1><a href="princekrish.html">Noor Sofa-Malt<a></h1>
            <p class="price">₹10000</p>
            <p>Noor Sofa One of the most luxurious models designed for the ultimate comfort and relaxation.</p>
            <p><button class="btn-cart">Add to Cart</button></p>
          </div>
          <div class="product-card">
            <img src="images/coral sofa.jpg" alt="Diana Sofa-Coral" class="product-img">
            <h1><a href="princekrish.html">Diana Sofa-Coral<a></h1>
            <p class="price">₹10000</p>
            <p>Diana Sofa One of the most luxurious models designed for the ultimate comfort and relaxation</p>
            <p><button class="btn-cart">Add to Cart</button></p>
          </div>
          
    </section>
```

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YEbK.png)
[How its supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWkwy.png)

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible code, so that we can better understand what you have done. In this example you have added CSS for downstuff but there is no element with that class.

Comment: You have to apply margin bottom to the content div. If you reproduce your issue here then we can help you out.

Comment: @MdJunaidAlam Oh im sorry; accidentally attached the wrong code

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Could you please elaborate

Comment: You told it is overlapping right. Can you put that code also?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Yes, its done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a template for you. This is probably what you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <title>Your Page Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
  *,
  *::after,
  *::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #737373;
    padding: 1rem;
  }

  body {
    display: flex; /* Use flex */
    flex-direction: column; /* Make it flex column this is the trick */
  }

  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  .item {
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    flex-basis: 25%;
    height: 450px;
  }

  .downstuff {
    margin-top: auto; /* Align element to bottom */
    align-self: flex-end; /* Align element to right */
    color: white;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="downstuff">
    <p>Copyright © 2021 Oaknoak | Branded Furniture</p>
    <p>Manufacturer | Chennai</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```